# $stateProvider.go() ignored using Cordova (emulating Android)

Tags: angularjs, cordova, angular-ui-router

I have a Cordova app developed. Whenever I try to do `cordova run android` it opens the app but when the controller has to do a `$state.go('app.login')` is being ignored. This is happening only when emulating with **Android**. If I try `cordova run browser` or `cordova run ios` it works OK.

This is part of my App.config:

```
App.config(['$stateProvider','$urlRouterProvider','$httpProvider',
function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $httpProvider) {
  'use strict';
  // default route to dashboard
  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('page.login');
  //
  // App Routes
  // -----------------------------------
  $stateProvider
    .state('app', {
        url: '/app',
        abstract: true,
        templateUrl: basepath('app.html'),
        controller: 'AppController'
    })
    .state('page.login', {
        url: '/login',
        templateUrl: 'app/pages/login.html',
        controller: 'LoginController',
    });
    // Change here your views base path
    function basepath(uri) {
      return 'app/views/' + uri;
    }
});
```

I think it has something to do with the paths... But I don't know what exactly is going on.
Cheers!

**UPDATE**
I've just realised this: if I do a `console.log($state.go('app.login'))` I get this

```
a {$$state: Object, then: function, catch: function, finally: function}
  $$state: Object
    status: 2
    value: Error
      message: "transition prevented"
      stack: (...)
      get stack: function () { [native code] }
      set stack: function () { [native code] }
      __proto__: d
    __proto__: Object
 __proto__: Object
```

Comment: So there are no errors in the console when you use `chrome://inspect#devices`?

Comment: James_Parsons check my last update